# Can't find IP for NAS mapped in file explorer Win11 after router upgrade

Tags: router, nas

Just upgraded my home router from a Netgear Nighthawk R7000 to a TP-Link Deco WE10800.

I can see my NAS in Win11 file explorer but nowhere else.

Both the Router Admin page on the computer web page and the router mobile app list all devices with IP & MAC addresses except the router. I can even see one other wired device.

I got a feeling this is something on the router, a Synology 2 Bay NAS DiskStation DS718

CMD nslookup shows my nas connected to a DNS address which looks like my Spectrum Modem.

But I'm unsure how to proceed.

My nas is
`\\nascat\chip`

Some command prompt info

```
C:\Users\Marc>net use
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           Z:        \\nascat\chip             Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.


C:\Users\Marc>nslookup chip
Server:  209-018-047-062.inf.spectrum.com
Address:  209.18.47.62

*** 209-018-047-062.inf.spectrum.com can't find chip: Non-existent domain

C:\Users\Marc>ping nascat

Pinging nascat.local [fe80::211:32ff:fe99:bac9%25] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::211:32ff:fe99:bac9%25: time=2ms
Reply from fe80::211:32ff:fe99:bac9%25: time=2ms
Reply from fe80::211:32ff:fe99:bac9%25: time=2ms
Reply from fe80::211:32ff:fe99:bac9%25: time=2ms

Ping statistics for fe80::211:32ff:fe99:bac9%25:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 2ms

C:\Users\Marc>ping chip
Ping request could not find host chip. Please check the name and try again.
```

Comment: `chip` appears to be a Share on the server `nascat`. it is normal to not be able to ping or nslookup a share name. only the server name is valid for those commands. it looks like the new router has replaced your DNS, and is using zero-conf configuration like the .local domain. is the issue you are having that your ping/nslookup are returning IPv6 addresses? Synology Assistant is helpful for finding NASs when you are unsure of the IP. perhaps it can help

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I had set my NAS to a static IP and/or had port forwarding to the NAS on my old Netgear. I changed the Deco to be on the same subnet that my Netgear was. The default LAN IP address of Deco is 192.168.68.1. Netgear default subnet was 192.168.1.1. So I changed the Deco to 192.168.1.1. and all is good. I know there are more details to elaborate on, but I'm good it's up and running now :)